# Can I leave one of the pergola legs unattached to the ground (just sitting on the patio)?

Tags: patio, pergola

I am planning to install a pergola over the table and 6 chairs that sit at the corner of my rectangular concrete bricks patio.
I am going to dig to install post supports for the three legs that will sit close to the edge of patio, on my lawn but for the forth I would just like to leave it on the patio (it will bear weight but it will not be screwed to a post support)

Is this doable ? Is it OK?

Comment: How do you plan to keep the bottom of the post from moving if someone crashes into it or accidentally rams furniture into it?

Comment: Good point. I might chose to screw it to a paver, that will not allow free movement but it will not count when strong wind  might cause a take off for the entire structure, that is the part that I am worried about
The above structure will fix the post in position up to a degree of lateral force applied. Above that the post will probably move if not screwed to a solid (concrete base) at the bottom